# What is the best database technology for storing OHLC historical prices?

Tags: database

Just for End-Of-Day data there will be billions of rows. What is the best way to store all that data. Is SQL Server 2008 good enough for that or should I look towards NoSQL solution, like MongoDB. Any suggestions?

That would be cool to have one master db with read/write permissions and one ore more replications of it for read only operations. Only master database will be used for adding new prices into the storage. Also that would be cool to be able replicate OHLC prices for most popular securities individually in order to optimize read access.

This data then will be streamed to a trading platform on clients' machines.

Comment: How you aggregate and query data is a critical factor in your decision. Without any mention of that in your question, answers will be subjective.

Comment: Think of an online broker website or webservice which has to provide historical stock price data to it's clients for analysis.

Comment: YOur best bet is to hire a datbase expert, someone with at least ten years experience running large systems with a lot of transactions and performance needs. This is complex stuff that you need an expert for. If you are asking this question, clearly you don't have the right people hired yet.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider Oracle [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) which is in production doing this within the infrastructure of a few well known stock exchanges.  Berkeley DB will allow you to record information at a master as simple key/value pairs, in your case I'd imagine a timestamp for the key and an encoded OHLC set for the value.  Berkeley DB supports single master multi-replica replication (called "HA" for High Availability) to support exactly what you've outlined - read scalability.  Berkeley DB HA will automatically fail-over to a new master if/when necessary.  Using some simple compression and other basic features of Berkeley DB you'll be able to meet your scalability and data volume targets (billions of rows, tens of thousands of transactions per second - depending on your hardware, OS, and configuration of BDB - see the [3n+1 benchmark with BDB](http://libdb.wordpress.com/3n1/) for help) without issue.

When you start working on accessing that OHLC data consider Berkeley DB's support for bulk-get and make sure you use the B-Tree access method (because your data has order and locality will provide much faster access).  Also consider the Berkeley DB partitioning API to split your data (perhaps based on symbol or even based on time).  Finally, because you'll be replicating the data you can relax the durability constraints to DB_TXN_WRITE_NOSYNC as long as your replication acknowledgement policy is requires a quorum of replicas ACK a write before considering it durable.  You'll find that a fast network beats a fast disk in this case.  Also, to offload some work from your master, enable peer-to-peer log replica distribution.

But, first read the [replication manager getting started guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17276_01/html/gsg_db_rep/C/repapp.html) and review the rep quote example - which already implements some of what you're trying to do (handy, eh?).

Just for the record, full disclosure I work as a product manager at Oracle on Berkeley DB products.  I have for the past nine years, so I'm a tad biased.  I'd guess that the other solutions - SQL based or not - might eventually give you a working system, but I'm confident that Berkeley DB can without too much effort.

---

Answer (score 1):

If you're really talking **billions** of new rows a day (Federal Express' data warehouse isn't that large), then you need an SQL database that can partition across multiple computers, like Oracle or IBM's DB2.

Another alternative would be a heavy-duty system managed storage like IBM's [DFSMS](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/storage/software/sms/whatis_sms/).

Comment: SQL Server can partition as well.

Comment: MonngoDB can also portion, doesn't it?

Comment: @HLGEM & Grief Coder:  Yep.  By the way, what's your network latency?  Remember, billions of rows inserted each and every day.  Over 11,000 rows a second.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc I happen to know Dow Jones uses SQL Server, I think it can handle the task if it is properly set up by someone who knows how to handle high transaction, large databases. Any database will not work properly in this scenario with an expert data person on hand to design.

Comment: @HLGEM: Yes, Dow Jones uses SQL Server.  According to this article, Dow Jones’ IT environment is fairly substantial: 6,000 servers worldwide, 1,700 network devices, almost 14,000 sourcetypes, 16 Splunk indexers and 100 GB of data per day.  http://blogs.splunk.com/2010/10/29/splunklive-new-york-dow-jones-reduces-server-monitoring-costs-by-60/  Go and do.

Comment: Yes and to do what he wants he is going to have a substantial IT investment no matter what database he chooses. That's one reason why I suggested that he needs to hire an expert as his first step. Anyone asking this question is not going to be able to set this sort of thing up on his own.

Comment: @HLGEM: I agree.  My experience is with large mainframes, so that's the direction I would go.  I suppose it's possible to build a server farm big enough to handle billions of transactions a day.  My opinion is that performance, scalability, and costs would be better overall using mainframes.

Comment: ANd that's fair. I just pointed out that the capability is there for SQL Server the same as for Oracle and DB2.